# Trouble linking search results using column data

Tags: php, mysql, search

im having trouble linking my search results using data from the database

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
$searchquery = $_POST['search'];
$searchquery = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchquery);


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_venues WHERE venue_name LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR venue_adress LIKE '%$searchquery%'") or die("Search failed!");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
    $output = 'No results found!';
    }else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $vname = $row['venue_name'];
            $vadress = $row['venue_adress'];
            $id = $row['venue_id'];


            $output .='<div id="searched">'.$vname.'<a href="venue.php?venue=" . $row['venue_id']?>"</a></div>';
        }
    }

}
```

?>

Above is my code, i need the id of the venue to be the specific page example being

venue.php?venue=$id

I think the issue is with the $output line

I can perform this normally but to get the search results to do this is proving difficult. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing `'` and `"`.  These two quote delimiters are a notorious pain in the neck when you're learning PHP. I think you're also putting the venue name string outside the `<a>` tag.

If I understand you right, you want this kind of thing in your output.

```
<div id="searched"><a href="venue.php?venue=7">Fillmore West</a></div>
```

If I were you, I'd use this construct for such things.

```
$output .= sprintf('<div id="searched"><a href="venue.php?venue=%d">%s</a></div>',
                   $row['venue_id'],$vname);
```

Using `sprintf()` makes your string substitution visible.

When you use single quotes `'string'` , php doesn't recognize anything in the string. That's appropriate for `sprintf()`'s first argument because it gets processed internally.